# What's the usage of blk_queue_segment_boundary()

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, block-device

The book ldd says for the function blk_queue_segment_boundary() like this:

> Some devices cannot handle requests that cross a particular size
>   memory bound- ary; if your device is one of those, use this function
>   to tell the kernel about that boundary. For example, if your device
>   has trouble with requests that cross a 4- MB boundary, pass in a mask
>   of 0x3fffff. The default mask is 0xffffffff.

I don't quite understand what the boundary means here, for example, I have a virtual block device, which are made of indeed 4MB files, so I want a request not exceed 4MB boundary,

```
unsigned long sector = blk_rq_pos(req);
unsigned long offset = sector << 9;
unsigned long nbytes = blk_rq_bytes(req);

int file_offset = offset % (1 << 22);
```

What I want is that (file_offset + nbytes) not greater than 4M, but indeed sometimes it exceeds 4M,
so, is there any misunderstanding of blk_queue_segment_boundary() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some controllers (particulary IDE) can not handle DMA requests that cross   memory regions at  4MB. Think of it as segment:index addressing where index can not be larger that the set boundary.

There is also a `blk_queue_max_segment_size`. Both are used to construct correct requests to the device - requests get reordered and merged.

There are other uses. For example, from `xen-blkfront.c`:

```
/* Each segment in a request is up to an aligned page in size. */
blk_queue_segment_boundary(rq, PAGE_SIZE - 1);
blk_queue_max_segment_size(rq, PAGE_SIZE);
```

Requests are limited to `PAGE_SIZE` for better performance.